# How to show the circle group $\mathbb{T}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^*/\mathbb{R}^+$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How to show the **circle group** $$\mathbb{T}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^*/\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: What is $C^*/R^+$ ?

Comment: Have you learned any theorems with quotients and isomorphisms in them?

Comment: From context it appears that $\mathbb C^*=\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ with multiplication, and $\mathbb R^+$ is the subgroup of positive real numbers with multiplication, but I agree with @Amr that it wouldn't hurt to make this explicit.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I see. Just to make sure what is the circle group ?

Comment: @Amr: It is the set as specified above (the unit circle in the complex plane) as a subgroup of $\mathbb C^*$ with multiplication.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer thanks.

Comment: @Amr: Many of these things can be looked up in Wikipedia: [circle group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about

$$f:C^*\to \Bbb T\,\,\,,\,\,f(z):=\frac{z}{||z||}\;\;?....$$

Comment: ..you are right...thank you!

Comment: @hxhxhx88: You can also show that $\Bbb T\cong\frac{\Bbb R}{\Bbb Z}$ via $\phi:\Bbb R\to \Bbb T, \phi(x)=\text{e}^{2\pi x i}$.